# mysql order by multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a `post` table and a `reply` table. both tables have a `created` column which record when it is being created. and the `post` table have a `last_reply_created` and is updated whenever a reply made to a post with that post id.

first question: in the posts page, I want to display all posts that sorted by whichever `last_reply_created` or `created` in post table comes first.

second question: Can you design the post and reply table better regarding this problem?

My workaround is to insert `last_reply_created` whenever a post is created.

Answer (score 1):

Your `last_reply_created` should be NULL until there is a reply and the creation time for a reply should always be more recent than the `created` value. This allows you to use [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) like this:

```
select *
from your_table
order by coalesce(last_reply_created, created) desc
```

And presumably every row has a non-NULL `created`.

I don't see any problem with caching the `last_reply_created` value in your post table. If you're going to be using it a lot then it doesn't make much sense to keep computing it over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I never noticed that change sir! Killed my answer as yours is sufficient :)

Comment: @David: I didn't mean to rain on your parade but you always have to keep an eye on those NULLs.